# window.open() set left has no effect in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following statement:

```
window.open(url, 
    windowName, 
    'width=' + screen.width + ',height=' + screen.height * 0.88
    + ',left=0,top=0');
```

This should open a window positioned at top left of monitor. I find out Chrome set the top correctly. As for left, no it does not. It is at left=7. If I set left=7, it opens at 7. If I set to 100, again, it opens at 7. (I open the test page containing the above `window.open` in 'New incognito window' .)

As the width = screen.width = 1920, the popup should cover the whole window. Now as left = 7, the popup window goes to the second monitor on the right (by about 9 pixels). How can I set it so that the left starts at 0?

Setting:
Window 10.
Two monitors.
Open the popup in the left monitor.
Chrome: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Picture for the left:

[image: Left starts at 7]

Picture for the right:

[image: Right already goes beyond 1920]

Answer (score 1):

You've missed comma before left
it should be

```
window.open(url, 
windowName, 
'width=' + screen.width + ',height=' + screen.height * 0.88
+ ',left=0,top=0');
```

Also you might need to round the height.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, I forget to copy the comma. In the original code, there is a comma before `left=0`.